# How to change current formatting in a AMSREdit control for VBA

Tags: excel, vba, richtext

I am using a control "MSREDIT Class" in an Excel Sheet, for Rich Editing purpose.

I did add this control on the Sheet via the menu Developer > Insert > More Controls: MSREdit Class. It is from the msrtedit 1.0 Type Library

This control supports cut/copy/paste (CTRL-A, CTRL-V, CTRL-X, etc...) but not usual shortcuts for formatting (CTRL-B, CTRL-I, CTRL-U, ...)

I would like to implement these shortcuts, but I can't find how to do it. Changing the Font on the control does not affect new text.  I tried also to edit directly the RTF (via TextRTF property), adding tags like /b or /b0. But the problem is that I can't figure out the position of the cursor inside the "RTF" string...

Any idea how I should do this ? I don't find documentation for this library MSRTEDIT.DLL (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16)

Many thx in adv !

Comment: FYI: I have an alternative. Instead of using this MSREDIT control, I can use the Microsoft InkEdit Control,which has property to toggle on/off Bold, Italic and Underline.

Answer (score 1):

I found on Stack Overflow that an alternative to this control is the Microsoft InkEdit Control. I quickly found that I could replace the MSREdit everywhere by this InkControl, without impact on my code, and then handle the shortcut for formatting. Only for Ctrl-I, I had to overwrite the standard behaviour which is to add an horizontal tab...

```
Private Sub EditRemark_KeyDown(pKey As Long, ByVal ShiftKey As Integer)
    CTRLI = False
    If ShiftKey = 2 And pKey = 73 Then
        'CTRL-I is producing a horizontal tab and must be ignored
        CTRLI = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub EditRemark_KeyPress(Char As Long)
    'Don't accept horizontal from CTRL-I
    If Char = 9 And CTRLI Then Char = 0
End Sub

Private Sub EditRemark_KeyUp(pKey As Long, ByVal ShiftKey As Integer)
    If ShiftKey = 2 Then
        Select Case pKey
        Case 66
            EditRemark.SelBold = Not EditRemark.SelBold
        Case 73
            EditRemark.SelItalic = Not EditRemark.SelItalic
        Case 85
            EditRemark.SelUnderline = Not EditRemark.SelUnderline
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Copy/pasting RichText/Images works like a charm :)